# Bootstrap Navbar with Affix loses height when scrolling down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I am creating a website with a bootstrap navbar that uses affix, but when I scroll down to the point the navbar goed to the top of the page. the navbar loses its height.

How can I make it that the navbar keeps it height, so the page doesnt collapse a bit?

I dont realy know how I can explain this very good, so here is my website where I try to fix it http://beta.sanderjochems.com/blog

Thanks,
Sander Jochems

HTML Code:

```
    <div class="top">
      <h1 class="top-title">Sander Jochems</h1>
    </div>

<!-- Header -->

    <nav class="navbar" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="297">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand accent" href="">Sander Jochems</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="/home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="/projects"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> Projects</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-android"></i> App Inventor <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="/appinventor/extensions">Extensions</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/appinventor/snippets">Snippets</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/appinventor/examples">Examples</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="/portfolio"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> Portfolio</a></li>
              <li class="active"><a href="/blog"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
/* HEADER */

.navbar-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
}

.navbar-wrapper .container {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.navbar {
    z-index:9;
}

.accent {
    display: inline;
}

/* AFFIX */

.affix {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

/* TOP */

.top {
    height:300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    background-image:url("../../image/header/top.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}

.top-title {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Baloo Tammudu', cursive;
    font-size:80px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adjusting your `data-offset-top` attribute on your `nav` tag?

Comment: Yes @cwanjt. I have changed it from 280 to 320 with all the numbers between it. It didnt fix it. It only went to the top at another point

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but try a value of 360.

Comment: @cwanjt its not the data-offset-top attr. Its that the navabr goes to overlay mode

Comment: @SanderJochems website url no longer working, please update it, or try to better describe the issue.